# CakePHP Base Url with Query String

Tags: cakephp

I'm having an issue with one of my cake apps. It's actually pretty custom, so I'm not surprised Cake isn't handling this very special case gracefully.

I want my application to have a baseUrl = 'addonmodules.php?module=phusion'

I've tried a few variations of the change in my config.php:

`Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME').'?module=phusion');`
`Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME').'?module=phusion&url=');`
`Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME').'&#63;module=phusion');`
`Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME').'&#63;module=phusion&#38;url=');`

but I can't seem to be able to get this to work. Any assistance with this would be much appreciated.

If you need more information I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13660262/1868660

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue:

Add this lines in config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', 'addonmodules.php?module=phusion');
Configure::write('App.base', '/path/to/webroot/');
```

also you may need to manually set the the url parameter

```
if(!isset($_GET['url'])) $_GET['url'] = '/';
```

I know this is an old question, but stumbled myself into something similar and hope it would be useful. 
Thanks to ADmad from #cakephp for his help in making this work.