# How to get the base Url in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I'm using `Html Helper css()` method to link my stylesheets just like this: `<?php echo $this->Html->css('reset.css');?>` but what if my CakePHP app is accessed through a path other than `http://site.domain.com`, i.e. `http://site.domain.com/my_app`

What would be the best command to link my stylesheet?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13660262/1868660

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The exact same command should work:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->css('reset.css');
?>
```

It automatically adds the path to the CSS folder if the given path `'reset.css'` doesn't start with a slash.

By the way, if you do need to get the base url in Cake, you can use the `Router` class:

```
//with http://site.domain.com/my_app
echo Router::url('/')       //-> /my_app
echo Router::url('/', true) //-> http://site.domain.com/my_app
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different ways to get the base path.
I use

```
echo $this->webroot; //Note: auto appends trailing slash
```

Comment: What if this only returns a URL of / instead of /app/webroot?

Comment: Will work only at controller level. check @nIcO answer

Answer (score 6):

Use this for baseurl

```
echo $this->html->url('/', true);
```

Comment: Will work only at view level. check @nIcO answer for generic solution

Answer (score 4):

On a related note.

If you need the theme url you can do this:

```
$this->webroot.'theme/'.$this->theme
```

Answer (score -1):

You must format:
WWW_ROOT . DS . 'css/file.css';

Comment: WWW_ROOT have the full path route to webroot, not the url.