# How do you generate a link to the base URL in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a template where I want to generate an anchor to the base URL of my application. In my case the method which handles this is `FrontController::index()`.

If it was just a simple link, I can easily do this inside a template:

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Home', ['controller' => 'Front', 'action' => 'index']); ?>
```

However, instead of just a simple link with the text "Home" I want to wrap an anchor tag around some other markup. The output I want in plain HTML (not using Cake's helper methods) would be:

```
 <a href="/">
     <img class="app-logo" src="/app-logo.png"> 
     <span class="app-name">App name</span>
 </a>
```

I've read [How to get the base Url in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738711/how-to-get-the-base-url-in-cakephp) and none of the methods in there work:

```
echo $this->webroot; // produces 'false'
echo Router::url('/'); // produces 'Class 'App\Controller\Router' not found`
```

CakePHP 3.5.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Router Class

```
<a href="<?= \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Front', 'action' => 'index']) ?>">
    <img class="app-logo" src="/app-logo.png"> 
    <span class="app-name">App name</span>
</a>
```

Edit: CakePHP 3.x uses Namespaces. You have to use the fully qualified class name or add a use statement to the top of your script.

```
echo \Cake\Routing\Router::url(...);
```

or

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

echo Router::url(...);
```

Comment: You can also use the `link` function, replacing `'Home'` with your desired content (which can in turn be generated with HTML helper functions, if you want), and adding `['escape' => false]` after the URL parameter.