# URL always appended? CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I'm new for CakePHP; 
The URL address bar is always appended after I clicked on every menu;

I have defined my routes as below:

```
Router::connect('/brand/*', array('controller' => 'phones', 'action' => 'phonebybrand'));
```

This is my menu:

```
<?php            
        foreach ($phonebrands as $phonebrand):
            echo '<li><a href="brand/{$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['id']}">{$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['brandname']}</a></li>';
        endforeach;
?>
```

I tried to click my menu for several times; what I found out is the URL always appended;
1st time: localhost/cakephp-2.3.2/brand/43 
2nd time: localhost/cakephp-2.3.2/brand/brand/43 
3rd time: localhost/cakephp-2.3.2/brand/brand/brand/43

Please help me, why it's always appended the url?

Thank.

Comment: How are you creating that menu? Can you show some code?

Comment: Maybe show us how the link is generated? Actually, we'll just use telepathy

Comment: add the code of your menu..

Comment: I updated my problem above, Please help me.
Thank @JoseVega ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably not getting the base url correctly.

Try this in your view

```
<?php            
    foreach ($phonebrands as $phonebrand) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->Html->url('/', true).'brand/{$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['id']}">    {$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['brandname']}</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Otherwise replace `$this->Html->url()`with `Router::url('/', true);`.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298552/base-url-in-cakephp) might help.

Comment: Finally, I found the problem; because I didn't point it back to the controller I also changed it to like $this->html->url();
**Check my code below; it's working now:**
`echo '<li>'.$this->Html->link($phonebrand['Phonebrand']['brandname'],array('controller'=>'phones','action'=>'phonebybrand',$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['id'])).'</li>';`

Thank You !

Comment: It does look much better, but that link doesn't show the `localhost/cakephp-2.3.2/phones/phonebybrand/$id` link instead of the `localhost/cakephp-2.3.2/brands/$id` you were trying to make? I've update the answer with the two options to see what you'll get. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Yes, I got it.
Thank for you helping.  ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are probably adding "cakephp-2.3.2/brand/43" instead of "/cakephp-2.3.2/brand/43"

Answer (score 0):

What happends when you replace your menu code with:

```
<?php            
        foreach ($phonebrands as $phonebrand):
            echo '<li><a href="/brand/{$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['id']}">{$phonebrand['Phonebrand']['brandname']}</a></li>';
        endforeach;
?>
```